What is the difference between the Vedantic philosophies of Advaita, Vishista Adwaita, Dwaita, Shudh Adwaita and BhedAbhed?
The prominent philosophies of spiritual practice includes the Adwaita of Adi Sankracharya, Vishista Adwaita of Ramanujacharya, Dwaita of Madhavacharya, Shudha Advaita of Vallabhacharya and BhedAbhed of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu.
In what all respects do all these schools of spirituality differ? And are there any other similar philosophies?

This question is similar to: Dvaita vs Advaita vs Vishistadvaita vs Shuddhadvaita vs any other. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
